# C int types and _Generic. Which types are compatible?

Tags: c, macros

I want to make a macro that checks if a given value is an integer or not, and I found that some integer types are compatible with each other when using `_Generic`, so they can't both be used as separate `_Generic` cases.

like `int` and `int32_t`

or

`signed char` and `int8_t`

what is the rule on that? Is there a solution that works with all platforms/compilers?

my current code is:

```
#define is_integer(exp) \
_Generic(exp, \
    int8_t: 1, \
    int16_t: 1, \
    int32_t: 1, \
    int64_t: 1, \
    uint8_t: 1, \
    uint16_t: 1, \
    uint32_t: 1, \
    uint64_t: 1, \
    default: 0)
```

However, it doesn't work with `char` (goes to default), but works with `signed char` (goes to `int8_t`).

Should I add `char` as a separate `_Generic` case? I'm afraid that some implementation `typedef`s `int8_t` to `char` so it won't work, or are they not allowed to?

Comment: Why do you want to check it? I think you are trying to solve X-Y problem

Comment: @gulpr I need a macro that returns 1 if arg is an integer, and 0 if it's not

Comment: What for? That was my question.

Comment: @gulpr one example is to make sure the arguments of other macros are provided correctly, like so:

`#define array_put_at(arr, val, at)
do {
_Static_assert( is_integer(at), "arg 3 must be an integer type");
arr[at] = val;
} while(0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a solution that works with all platforms/compilers?

Note that `(u)intN_t` are *optional* types.

On implementations with the usual `(u)intN_t` types, consider a 2-stage `_Generic`.

```
#define is_integer2(exp) \
_Generic(exp, \
    int8_t: 1, \
    int16_t: 1, \
    int32_t: 1, \
    int64_t: 1, \
    uint8_t: 1, \
    uint16_t: 1, \
    uint32_t: 1, \
    uint64_t: 1, \
    default: 0)

#define is_integer1(exp) \
_Generic(exp, \
    char: 1, \
    signed char: 1, \
    unsigned char: 1, \
    ...  // 2 shorts, int, unsigned, 2 longs
    long long: 1, \
    unsigned long long: 1, \
    default: is_integer2(exp))
```

Code can include `(u)intptr_t` in another level.

Code can include `size_t, ptrdif_t` in another level.

Code can include `(u)intmax_t` in another level.

Etc.

Comment: this actually works. Putting possible collisions in another `_Generic` at the default case stops the compiler from complaining about multiple matches

Comment: @AbdulmalekAlmkainzi IMO, C should be changed to allow collisions and use the first one on the list.

Answer (score 1):

Types like `int16_t` are allowed to be mapped to any standard or extended integer type having the appropriate characteristics, if any exist, chosen in arbitrary fashion.  Likewise types like `int_least16_t`, except that for each such type of size 8, 16, 32, and 64, every conforming implementation must have at least one standard or extened integer type having the appropriate characteristics.

If on two implementations both `int` and `long` are 32 bits, but one of them happens to define `int32_t` as `int` an the other defines it as `long`, then on the first implementation `int32_t` will be compatible with `int` but incompatible with `long`, while on the second `int32_t` will be compatible with `long` but incompatible with `int`.

Comment: What about char? You avoid this issue

Comment: @gulpr: While I would expect that most implementations would map `int8_t` to `signed char` and `uint8_t` to `unsigned char`, I don't think anything would forbid an implementation where `char` is always unsigned to map `uint8_t` to that type rather than `unsigned char`.  Likewise one where it was always signed might legitimately define `int8_t` as `char`.  Too bad there's no concept of "any type which hasn't been explicitly mentioned yet, but is representation-compatible with [e.g.] int8_t", since that would solve a lot of problems.

Comment: @supercat I see. So is making a (somewhat) portable `is_integer` not possible?

Comment: @supercat no you cant typed `int8_t` as `char` as most compilers allow you to change the signes of `char` using command switches. It ***has*** to be explicit.

Comment: @gulpr: Switching the signedness of `char` with a command-line switch is technically switching between two C implementations, and, were aliasing `char` an issue, this could be managed by conditionally aliasing it to one type or another. GCC provides preprocessor definitions that header files such as `<stdint.h>` can use to select different code. However, in no conforming C implementation can both `char` and `signed char` be aliased to the same type or can both `char` and `unsigned char` be, because `char` must be a distinct type from both `signed char` and `unsigned char`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil so `char` is distinct from `signed char` and `unsigned char`. Is it also distinct from other integer types?

Comment: @AbdulmalekAlmkainzi: The 11 “classic” integer types, `char`, `signed char`, `short int`, `int`, `long int`, `long long int`, `unsigned char`, `unsigned short int`, `unsigned int`,`unsigned long int`, and `unsigned long long int`, must be different types, per C 2018 6.2.5 14. (Some of them have aliases; `short` and `short int` are the same thing.) The types of `<stdint.h>` may alias these or other types defined by the C implementation.

Comment: @EricPostpischil oh so its probably better to use them rather than `<stdint.h>` types for my macro right?

Comment: @AbdulmalekAlmkainzi: Integer types in C were defined at a time when all that really mattered was a type's representation.  If `char` was a signed 8-bit integer, there would be no reason to care about whether an implementation recognized it as a different type from `signed char`.  When C89 was published, as a compromise between those who would think the types should be compatibile and those who thought they should be incompatible, the Standard requires that implementations issue at least one diagnostic when fed a program that attempts to covnert a `char*` to a `signed char*` even if both...

Comment: ...character types have the same representation, but an implementation could then go on and treat the types as equivalent after that.  Then when C99 was added, nobody thought it would matter if `int32_t` was the same type as `int` or `long`, and thus nobody bothered to write good rules about type compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to make a macro that checks if a given value is an integer or not…

```
#define Test(x) _Generic((x) + (uintmax_t) 0, uintmax_t: 1, default: 0)
```

In the `+` expression, any integer `x` will be converted to `uintmax_t`, and the expression type will be `uintmax_t`.

Any floating-point, complex, or pointer type will cause the expression to have a different type, so the default case will be selected. Arrays and functions will also fall into this case the first operand of `_Generic` is subject to array-to-pointer and function-to-pointer conversion.

Other types, such as structures, will cause errors.

Comment: I see. But I actually want the macro to return 0 given any non-integer type, including structs and unions.

Answer (score 0):

Look at `<stdint.h>` and you most likely will find that `int8_t` is aliased to `signed char`. As `signed char != char` your macro will fail with `char`.

Comment: so adding `char` as a case to the `_Generic` will work and is portable?